# BASH redirect create folder

Tags: bash

How can I have the following command

```
echo "something" > "$f"
```

where `$f` will be something like `folder/file.txt` create the folder `folder` if does not exist?

If I can't do that, how can I have a script duplicate all folders (without contents) in directory 'a' to directory 'b'?

e.g if I have

a/f1/
a/f2/
a/f3/

I want to have

b/f1/
b/f2/
b/f3/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The other answers here are using the external command `dirname`. This can be done without calling an external utility.

```
mkdir -p "${f%/*}"
```

You can also check if the directory already exists, but this not really required with `mkdir -p`:

```
mydir="${f%/*}"
[[ -d $mydir ]] || mkdir -p "$mydir"
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the correct syntax is actually `${f%/*}`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Sorry, I had gave you the alternative to `basename`, not `dirname`.

Comment: What does `-d $mydir` do?

Comment: What are all of the extra symbols for in `${f%/*}`?

Comment: @AndrewKirna returns true if the next argument is a directory. See the output of `help test`.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm. I didn’t see anything about %/* on the link you sent though.

Comment: Got it! %/* removes anything matching /* starting at the end of the string one time. Thanks.

Comment: Where does "something" go from the original example?

Answer (score 11):

```
echo "something" | install -D /dev/stdin $f
```

Comment: +1 for the concise solution. However, the answer could be much better with just a few words of explanation.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
mkdir -p `dirname $f` && echo "something" > $f
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mkdir -p` to create the folder before writing to the file:

```
mkdir -p "$(dirname $f)"
```